# How to set Eclipse Help Scope

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin where you select text from the editor, press a shortcut(in my case it's alt+F1) and the Eclipse help search opens and automatically searches for that selected text.

Here is the code:

```
public class Button1 extends AbstractHandler {

    public Button1() {}

    public String getCurrentSelection()
    {
       IEditorPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
        if (part instanceof ITextEditor)
        {
        final ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor) part;
        ISelection sel = editor.getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
        if (sel instanceof TextSelection)
            {
            ITextSelection textSel = (ITextSelection) sel;
                return textSel.getText();
            }
        }
    return null;
    }

    public void searchInHelp(String str) {
        IWorkbenchHelpSystem help = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem();
        help.search(str);
    }

    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        String str = getCurrentSelection();
        searchInHelp(str);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when the search is performed it's performed for all the Eclipse Help while I only want to apply it to a certain scope like, let's say, Workbench User Guide, so that it only searches there.

As far as I've seen in IWorkbenchHelpSystem there is no handling of Help Search Scope, and, from what I've been told, everything that deals with the scope is in an internal package so it is not intended for use by other plugins.

I did found something like this:

```
String qualifier = ResourcesPlugin.getDescriptor().getUniqueIdentifier();
String key = ResourcesPlugin.PREF_AUTO_BUILDING;
boolean value = true;
IScopeContext context = new ProjectScope(MyProject);
IEclipsePreferences node = context.getNode(qualifier);
if (node != null)
    node.putBoolean(key, value);
```

But I have no idea if this ProjectScope has anything to do with the Eclipse Help Scope or how to correctly integrate it with my code (i.e just add it in a method and call it before doing the search?).

So can anyone help me out on how to set the help scope when performing the search?

Comment: 'ProjectScope' is for preferences, nothing to do with help.

Comment: Thought as much, thanks again, Greg! Unfortunately, it seems I'll have to drop my idea of changing Help Search scope through code. By the way, do you have any idea if there is a method, like search(), but to check inside the browser? help.search("string") only works if the help search opens in the dynamic help view, if I try to open through help browser it will open the browser but not search anything. As far as I've looked though IWorkbenchHelpSystem, there isn't, but maybe you know some workarounds.